# License of papers on arxiv

Tags: licensing, commercial, cc-by-nc-sa

I'm wondering if I can use any paper from arxiv.org for building commercial app. For better clarity let's say I want to build *myself* commercial app based on [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.04948) in which I can't find anything about its license. But there is also available [implementation](https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan) of this paper with *Attribution-NonCommercial 4.0 International* license. My question is - can I build commercial software that will be based on mentioned paper and it'll very similar to that implementation although it will be created by me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The arXiv papers themselves are published without a license, meaning all rights are reserved. However, this only affects the paper as a creative works, and it does not affect the content of the paper, for example any methods or algorithms outlined in the paper: knowledge and information cannot be copyrighted.

Inventions can be patented though. Just because some method is publicly known does not imply that it is free to use. It would be your obligation to determine whether a method is free to use.

The software you mentioned (StyleGAN) has a concrete license. If you Share or Adapt StyleGAN, you have to abide by the license terms. If you develop an independent software with the same functionality, and your software is not a derived work of StyleGAN, then you are not bound by StyleGAN's license terms.

So yes: provided that you are not infringing on any patents and that you do not derive from the StyleGAN software, you can implement the approach from the paper in a commercial software. You will hold sole copyright for your own software. Two caveats:

- As a matter of academic custom, it would be proper to cite the paper in your software's documentation. There is no legal obligation, though.
- The Network requires a training data set to work, and this data will also have some license. The FFHQ data set used by StyleGAN does not allow commercial use, so you would have to assemble your own dataset.